# Change table structure and data migration in MYSQL with only queries

Tags: mysql, database, structure

So i need to make this table change

**From**

```
assignments
 - id
 - organisation_id (fkey to organisations.id)

organisations
 - id

contacts
 - id
 - assignment_id (fkey to assignment.id)
```

**To**

```
assignments // Not altered
 - id
 - organisation_id

organisations // Not altered
 - id

contacts //Table altered (-assignment_id, +organisation_id)
 - id
 - organisation_id (fkey to organisations.id)

assignment_contact //New table with 2 foregin keys to existing tables
 - contact_id (fkey to contact.id)
 - assignment_id (fkey to assignment.id)
```

So I am wondering if this migration could be done with just MySQL queries, without having to do any manual after-treatment etc?

**"Obstacles"**

1. There is ~22k records in the "contacts" table
2. It has to be done in production, so there may not be any downtime longer than a couple of minutes

Any suggestions or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this migration can be done using mysql queries only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done in production without a problem,
The number of records ~22k is really low volume of data for Mysql.

The proposal is to create and populate the new table first.
Then create migration tables for tables that you enter, and populate them to.
Then you just swap the production tables with the migration ones (rename the existing to bkp_table_name, and the migration ones to real names). 
If everything is OK then you can drop the bkp_* tables.

Of course do a backup first, and have in mind table indexes.

edit: another suggestion is to use mysql terminal instead of Mysql workbench or phpmyadmin